# What is the meaning of Column_Name(+)='Value'

Tags: oracle

We have the Oracle Query received from customer, which has a condition like

```
table.column_name(+)='Value'
```

I want to get this converted to ANSI SQL for Hive database.
Can someone please assist in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is native Oracle join syntax. Despite what others say, it has never been deprecated, and is still used internally by Oracle and by many older programmers. Yet the newer syntax has been getting most of the new enhancements and so is slowly replacing the older syntax. In the world of Oracle it's important to be proficient with both.

`table.column_name(+) = 'Value'` means that on outer joining to `table`, check to see that the `column_name` is equal to `'Value'`, but if it doesn't equal `Value` (or is `NULL`), don't throw out the row, just leave all the columns from that table `NULL`. Without the `(+)` that predicate would throw out all non-matched rows because nothing equals `NULL`, and thus would convert it to an inner join.

The ANSI equivalent is:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN table ON [join key expression] AND table.column_name = 'Value'`

Which is quite different than:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table ON [join key expression]
WHERE table.column_name = 'Value'
```

This would fail the `NULL` equality test on all the non-matched rows and effectively convert the outer join to an inner join, just like `table.column_name = 'Value'` would do using native Oracle syntax. `table.column_name(+) = 'Value'` keeps it an outer join.

Comment: Nice answer! ...

Comment: I note that there's a good reason no one uses `(+)` syntax anymore - it's ambiguous because it defines joins at column level, not table level.

Comment: @Nick.Mc, it's not true that no one uses it anymore. Plenty of folks still do. And the ANSI syntax has its own ambiguities. Each has strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: True, it's a subjective statement. To be fair it's only Oracle that uses this syntax (AFAIK) and "greenfield" implemnentations of SQL (i.e. in Databricks) definitely do not include this syntax. I really would not recommend it's usage for any new work. If you are realistically doing new development work and still using this syntax, that's interesting. I'm happy to be informed of an example where SQL-92 syntax is just as ambiguous.

Comment: @Nick.Mc, yes, it is subjective - that's what preferences are, and which syntax you use is a preference we are free to make as we like. There are some cases where native Oracle syntax is better, and some cases where ANSI is better. I could write a whole paper on the weaknesses of ANSI and situations where native Oracle is better, but I can't really do that in a comment. I'll just give you one example out of many - to see the predicates impacting results with ANSI you have to look in two places often pages apart (`JOIN` and `WHERE`). With Native you have it all in one place. Advantage native.

Comment: SQL 92 certainly supports that type of syntax (squashing join and predicate into the `WHERE`), it just doesn't support `(+)` syntax. I would have certainly stuck to my guns and continued using `(+)` until I realised it allows you to write ambiguous code. So removing that syntax just removes one of many possible issues that may contribute to bugs or unexpected failures in code.